# When using GetHostAddresses how do I get the value of a ScriptProperty?

Tags: powershell

I'm using the following to get the IP address of a web service:

```
$o = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses("myservice.domain.com")
$o   correctly returns the object properties.

Address           : **********
AddressFamily     : InterNetwork
ScopeId           : 
IsIPv6Multicast   : False
IsIPv6LinkLocal   : False
IsIPv6SiteLocal   : False
IPAddressToString : 10.0.0.1
```

But if I do:

```
$o.IPAddressToString
```

Nothing is returned.

IPAddressToString is a ScriptProperty.

I need to get the IP address to feed into another script.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
$o[0].IPAddressToString
```

Or

```
$o[0].ToString()
```

The `GetHostAddresses` -- Note the last "s", making it plural.  You get back an *array* containing the IP(s) of the host.  If you need to iterate the entire array of addresses you can do the following:

```
foreach ($i in $o) { $i.IPAddressToString }
```

See this MSDN for more details [Dns.GetHostAddresses Method (System.Net)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.gethostaddresses(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: This option is more succinct.  Really appreciate the assist!

Comment: Agreed. updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but this is a working one liner

```
$ipAddy = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses("yahoo.com")[0].IPAddressToString;
```

Answer (score 0):

Expand the ScriptProperty to access the output value:

```
$IpAddress = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses("www.example.com") | select IPAddressToString -ExpandProperty IPAddressToString
```

Be aware that if the GetHostAddresses() medthod returns more than one IPAddress object, $IPAddress will contain multiple strings, so the safe way is either to either enumerate and return all IP Addresses as strings individually, or pick the first one:

```
$IpAddress = ([System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses("www.example.com"))[0]
```

like in jscott's suggestion